# Como detectar tema escuro através de CSS e Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Estou criando um site que deve ter cores mais leves no tema escuro e terei mais flexibilidade se houver como capturar se o usuário prefere tema claro ou escuro.

Sei que alguns sistemas operacionais e celulares possuem modos de "forçar" o tema escuro em alguns sites e queria saber se isso é detectável

Outra pergunta seria como impedir que o navegador force o tema escuro (o que prejudicaria o css/js caso este estivesse preparado para oferecer outras cores em caso de tema escuro ativo)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: A pergunta é muito boa, o titulo é claro, mas votei para fechar pois a resposta [linkada (Como funciona a media query prefers-color-scheme do CSS?)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/401353/3635) já mostra os meios de fazer isso, do meu ponto de vista o DevTools (e similares) são os melhores meios, já que o objetivo é visualizar mudanças em tempo de execução e provavelmente desenvolvimento, enxergar as mudanças provavelmente é o principal objetivo.

Comment: Observação: se você deseja detectar via JavaScript, você pode usar `matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');` ([documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia))